# React - passing JSON objects to all stateless child components

Tags: reactjs

I want to be able to do an ajax call, store a JSON array in a variable called "user" and make it available of all stateless child components in my app.

I'm unsure of where to place the getJSON call.

**JSON file:**

```
{
  "user": [{
    "firstName": "Cliff",
    "lastName": "Johnson",
    "fullName": "Cliff Johnson",
    "username": "cliffjohnson",
    "userId": "8675309",
    "email": "cliff@cliffjohnson.com",
    "avatarSrc": "../images/avatar.png"
  }]
}
```

**Entry Point file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
{/* import rest of pages Pages */}

window.React = React;

var user;
$.getJSON("./json/user.json", function(json){
user = json; // this is the object I want to make accessible to all children
});

render(
  (<Router history={hashHistory} >
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="/frames" component={Frames} />
      <Route path="/albums" component={Albums} />
      <Route path="/channels" component={Channels} />

      <Route path="/playlist" component={Playlist} />
      <Route path="/mode" component={Mode} />
      <Route path="/history" component={History} />
      <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
    </Route>
  </Router>), document.getElementById('content')
);
```

**App file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import SideNav from './SideNav/SideNav';
import Frames from './Frames/Frames';

const App = ({ children }) => (
  <div className="container">
    <aside id="sidenav">
      <SideNav />
    </aside>
    <main>
      {children || <Frames />}
    </main>
  </div>
);

App.propTypes = { 
  children: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default App;
```

**Example child component:**

```
import React from 'react';

const User = ({ avatarSrc, fullName }) => (

  <div className="user">
    <div className="avatar">
      <img src={user.avatarSrc} alt="User Avatar" />
    </div>  
    <div className="user-full-name">
      {user.fullName}
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default User;
```

Comment: To be honest, this sounds like you're trying to reinvent redux... Have you looked into using redux directly?

Comment: Nicole is correct. Redux handles what you're trying to accomplish really well. I'd recommend spending a few hours watching these tutorials: https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux. They're fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37309201/react-passing-json-object-into-const/37309467): you need to put `user` as state in your `App`, and `setState()` and pass it down the component tree through props.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    $.getJSON("./json/user.json", (json) => {
      this.setState({user: json}); // Use setState to render the loaded data
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <aside id="sidenav">
          <SideNav />
        </aside>
        <main>
          {/* Use cloneElement to add props to dynamic children */}
          {this.props.children ? React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {user: this.state.user}) : <Frames />}
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is how React "without Flux or Redux" is done. If you want to manage your data model outside your components then you *do* want Flux or Redux.

PS: I think you want to use an [`IndexRoute`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#indexroute-1) or [`IndexRedirect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#indexredirect) instead of render `children || <Frames />`.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. I'll just dig in my heels and sort this out :) I'm getting unexpected token error at the opening brace of state = { --- I'm new to react and jsx and still learning about states, lifecycle and all the available methods and syntax post ES5. i.e., class App extends vs. const App = ({}) vs. var App = React.createClass({})... thanks again!

Comment: `state = {};` is a class property, which didn't make it into ES6. Using Babel you can use the [class-properties transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/). Or you can just assign the property in the constructor. I'll update my example.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using babel.es2015 / ES6 and the latest React. Not sure how that would differ from your working CodePen. My <User /> component is actually nested 3 layers deep in other components (App>SideNav>SideNavFooter>User)... it's like a Russian doll. PM me your paypal email... would love to donate for your help!

Comment: CodePen's Babel is configured with all the extra goodies, so class properties are supported, but if you are compiling with strict ES6 features it won't work. The assignment in the constructor will work though.

Comment: Noobie question but what's the difference between "class App extends React.Component{...}" and "var App = React.createClass({...})"

Comment: `class` is the new way to do it with ES6, `createClass` is the old way to do it with ES5. They both result in components that function pretty much the same way, though there are [some differences in the API](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html). `const App = ({a, b}) => {}` is an ES6 *stateless function component*, and in ES5 you could do it with `var App = function(props){ }`. Stateless function components came in React 0.14. You can use ES6 or ES5 with any version of React.

Comment: Seems like one would want access to state and lifecycle quite a bit across an app so I'm trying learn the value of a stateless component. i.e. having access to state and not using it is better than needing state and not having it.

Comment: Well you try to *limit* state and what components "own the state", then you use props to pass the state data down to components. Many of your components don't really need state. ["Thinking in React"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state) does a good job explaining how state and props are used in an app.

Comment: Honestly, I'm the front end guy on this project and the backend folks are building that out in Java so I'll let them worry about how to hook everything up. I just want to deliver them a framework that makes sense for Java servlet integration on the Amazon aws platform.