# React - passing JSON object into const

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get a json object into a const. I'm comfortable doing it with vars, like

```
{this.props.user.map(function(user){...
```

But with the stateless const, I'm not exactly sure.

Where have I gone wrong here?

```
import React from 'react';

var user;
$.getJSON("./json/user.json", function(json){
    user = json;
});

const User = ({ user }) => (

  <div className="user">
    <div className="avatar">
      <img src={user.avatarSrc} height="30" />
    </div>  
    <div className="user-full-name">
      {user.fullName}
    </div>
  </div>
);

User.PropTypes = {
  avatarSrc: React.PropTypes.string,
  fullName: React.PropTypes.string
};

export default User;
```

**LINK TO A MORE DETAILED STRUCTURE OF MY APP:**

[React - passing JSON objects to all stateless child components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308286/react-passing-json-objects-to-all-stateless-child-components)

Comment: Why do you think you've done something wrong? What is happening versus what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: How do you use your <User> component?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatarSrc' of undefined. I use it in another component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you've written this component is not stateless (the `user` is state), so you shouldn't be using a [stateless functional component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions), you should be using a [stateful component class](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes):

```
class User extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    user: React.PropTypes.object
  };
  state = {};
  componentDidMount() {
    $.getJSON("./json/user.json", (json) => {
      this.setState({user: json});
    });
  }
  render() {
    let user = this.state.user;
    return (
      <div className="user">
        <div className="avatar">
          { user && <img src={user.avatarSrc} height="30" /> }
        </div>  
        <div className="user-full-name">
          { user && user.fullName }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here it is working in CodePen.](https://codepen.io/abeall/pen/vGqYEr?editors=0010)

Of course, you don't *have* to make this component stateful. You could move the state to a parent component (like a top level view) and pass the `user` down as props. Then you could use the stateless function component instead.

Comment: This is great... your second idea is probably closer to what I want to do because it extends beyond just this component. I am using react-starterify as my template and all the components are written in the "const" form. I'll post a link to another question I posted with more detail on the structure of the webapp.

Comment: You won't be able to make *all* your components as stateless functions (what you are calling the "const" form, but actually it doesn't have to be a const, just a function.) Loading JSON over HTTP is a form of state, so some component is going to have to be responsible for that state. You could store the state in an external store (like Flux or Redux) but you still have to `setState` in one of your components to render it in your component tree. This is what stateful component classes are for.

Answer (score 1):

You might think about doing something like this. This separates the job of fetching the data and displaying the data.

```
import React from 'react';
import User from './user';

class UserContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { user: {} }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $.getJSON("./json/user.json", function(json) {
      this.setState({user: json})
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <User {...this.state.user} />
  }
}

export default UserContainer;
```

---

```
import React from 'react';

const User = ({ avatarSrc, fullName }) => (
  <div className="user">
    <div className="avatar">
      <img src={avatarSrc} height="30" />
    </div>  
    <div className="user-full-name">
      {fullName}
    </div>
  </div>
);

User.PropTypes = {
  avatarSrc: React.PropTypes.string,
  fullName: React.PropTypes.string
};

export default User;
```